# Array of Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to create an array of threads and give each of them a function but not working

```
Reader *readers = new Reader[10];

thread *ts = new thread[10];

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    readers[i].setAll(q, "t" + i);
    ts[i] = thread(readers[i].run); //Error: "cannot be referenced. its a deleted function"
}
```

Run function:

```
void Reader::run(){
    log(this->source);
    log.log("starting");

    while (flag){
        this->m = this->q.get(this->source);
        log.log("retrieved " + m.toString());
        if (m.getData().compare("stop") && m.getTarget().compare(this->source))
        {
            log.log("stopping");
            this->setFlag(false);//stop the current thread if the message is "stop"
        }
        else{
            if (!m.getTarget().compare(source)){//if the message isnt from the current thread then put the message back
                string dest = m.getSource();
                m.setSource(this->source);
                log.log("putting back [" + dest + "->" + m.getTarget() + ":" + " " + m.getData() + "] as " + m.toString());
                q.put(m);
                log.log("done putting back " + m.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm actually trying to do the following code:

```
thread t0(readers[0].run);
thread t1(readers[1].run);
etc...
```

but it also gives me the same error seen below:

[image: The error message]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler doesn't issue a grammatically incorrect error such as "cannot be referenced its a deleted function".

Comment: @interjay, look at this : http://srv1.jpg.co.il/4/543d4e5272bcd.png

Comment: The message in the screenshot shows two setences. That's why your comment is grammatically wrong when you omit all interpunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using c++11 you might want to take advantage of the nice memory management and binding features:

(edit: updated code in response to comments)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct runner
{
    void run() {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<runner>> runners;
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
        runners.emplace_back(new runner);
    }

    vector<thread> threads;
    for(const auto& r : runners) {
        threads.emplace_back(&runner::run, r.get());
    }

    for(auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for `bind`: `thread` has a variadic constructor that does the same thing. And no need for `unique_ptr`, just `vector<runner> runners(10);` would do the same thing.

Comment: And the second loop can be simplified somewhat: `for (auto & r : runners) threads.emplace_back(&runner::run, &r);`

Answer (score 0):

While `readers[i].run` looks like it should bind an object to a member function to make a callable object, sadly it doesn't. Instead, you need to pass a pointer to the member function and a pointer (or reference wrapper) to the object as separate arguments:

```
thread(&Reader::run, &readers[i]);    // or std::ref(readers[i])
```

or you might find it nicer to wrap the function call in a lambda:

```
thread([=]{readers[i].run();})
```

Comment: Hmmm but why would a compiler try to use `thread(const thread&)` instead of complaining that the method does not exist (or there are troubles with it, like being a member function or whatever appropriate). I don't see a path that would invoke the deleted copy constructor.

Comment: @luk32: I've no idea why that particular compiler might react in that particular way to invalid code. I'm just describing how to fix the code.

Comment: Oh, I knew you were right of course. I was just wondering if there is a logical valid conversion path to fallback to the offending constructor, because I don't see it and I find the error misleading. I guess the compiler got lost by itself a little bit as well.

Comment: @luk32: No, there's no logic. Presumably the compiler made up a type for the invalid constructor argument, and carried on trying to make sense of the constructor call, when it would have been better to give up at that point.